# SQL Server вопрос по запросу

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Г_3_Медицинский_работник]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[Телефон_сотр] CHECK  (([Г_3_Телефон] like '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-
[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' OR [Г_3_Телефон] like [dbo].[Телефон_умолчания]))
GO
```

Есть следующее ограничение. Суть его в том, что бы по умолчания ставилось значение из базы сохраненное в значениях по умолчанию. Когда я пишу так, мне выводит ошибку:

```
Не удалось привязать составной идентификатор "dbo.Телефон_умолчания".
```

Я хотел бы узнать как мне использовать это значение по умолчанию. Может кто то знает как поправить это.